# Where can I ask question details about ISO 8601 (date-time standard)?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

We have a purpose to support ISO 8601 and many other formats because the software will work in many different countries. Where can I ask question about date-time standards (like ISO 8601) and differences between them?

I asked a question in "Software Engineering" but it was closed because it's off-topic:
[What are the differences between national standards of ISO8601?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/439129/what-are-the-differences-between-national-standards-of-iso8601)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that SE has a site to ask [What are the differences between national standards of ISO8601?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/439129/what-are-the-differences-between-national-standards-of-iso8601) as it looks to me to require more focus, but you might find helpful to search for related questions on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [Stack Overflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) and learn from them how to ask  questions on these sites about [i18n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization).

## [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

### Related tags

[iso](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iso), [standards](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standards), [date-format](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date-format), [internationalization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internationalization)

### Related question

- [Internationalization : What things to think about?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/87452/233431)

## [Stack Overflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

### Related tags

[iso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iso), [standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/standards), [iso8601](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iso8601), [date-formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date-formatting), [internationalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internationalization)